# Periodically remove documents from Elasticsearch index depending on field

Tags: elasticsearch, jobs

Let's say I have an index called `car`. The documents in car have the following fields:

- `constructionYear`
- `seats`
- `decommissioned`
- …

Now I want to periodically delete all documents where `decommissioned` is `true`.

Is there a way to configure such a job on the Elasticsearch server? Or do I have to perform a REST call every time I want to clean up the index?

Comment: And why would you need to delete them, in first place? Why just marking them "decommisioned" isn't enough?

Comment: Adding to @yuri-g's question: Why don't you just exclude those documents from your queries and aggregations? By the way, your aggregations will be faster when you filter out some results ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'd need to build a delete by query to manage this, and then schedule it outside of Elasticsearch to be run every so often. there's no inbuilt scheduler for Elasticsearch to do this

however, to the point of Yuri's comment above, why not just leave them? you can still run analytics on the data

Comment: because sometimes I want to keep important data for 30 days and less important data for 14 days. 

Ex: remove `trace` after 1 day, remove `debug` after 14 days. All the rest can be stored for 30+ days.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can utilize a Watcher for this purpose.

It's not what they made for, yet you can set the Webhook Action there to go through whatever your Search input returns & do a REST call to delete unwanted docs by ID.

That way you're be able to keep it within your Elastic cluster.

P.S. Though it make sense to rethink your "data model" a bit, really.

Elasticsearch is not what your regular RDBMS is, and selective delete could get VERY expensive.

It's better to leave them sit there & simply modify your queries to acknowledge that attribute.